# In pure virtual calls keep CRTP pattern from overflowing

Tags: c++, crtp, pure-virtual, virtual-functions

Consider the following standard CRTP example:

```
#include<iostream>

template<class Derived>
struct Base {
    void f() { static_cast<Derived *>(this)->f(); }
    void g() { static_cast<Derived *>(this)->g(); }
};

struct Foo : public Base<Foo> {
    void f() 
     { 
      std::cout << 42 << std::endl; }
     };

int main() 
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.f(); // just OK
    foo.g(); // this will stack overflow and segfault
}
```

If this was regular virtual inheritance I could have mark virtual `f` and `g` methods as pure like :

```
struct Base 
{
    virtual void f()= 0;
    virtual void g()= 0;
};
```

and get a compile time error about `Foo` being abstract. But CRTP offers no such protection. Can I implement it somehow? Runtime check is acceptable too. I thought about comparing `this-> f` pointer with `static_cast <Derived *> (this)->f`, but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: okay thanks @quentin

Comment: Uh, you're welcome, I guess? Not sure what you're trying to do by copying another question exactly. If you want clarifications, you should ask there.